# Perform query on multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, automation, postgis

I need to apply the following query to 60+ tables:

```sql
UPDATE variable_table_name ab
SET    elem_nr = ef.elem_nr
FROM   ga_mit_elemnr ef
WHERE  (ab.elem_nr NOT IN
              (SELECT elem_nr
               FROM   strassenelemente cd)
       OR     ab.elem_nr IS NULL)
AND    St_within(ab.geom, ef.geom)
```

Is there a way to automate this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: is it the same model for all 60+ tables?

Comment: yes, its the same, only the updated table is different.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware it is not possible to do this in Plain SQL, however you could use PL/pgSQL to execute the query as dynamic command in a for loop and run this query against your 60+ tables. You can read about Pl/pgSQL here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql.html

Depending on your requirements you could also use other programming languages such as Python to dynamically execute SQL-statements as string.

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the case, I would suggest using postgres partitioning mechanism

I.e have a master table and 60+ partitions, each partition will be attached to the master, and on `ALTER TABLE` you alter only the master table schema, and all the rest will be updated as well

Answer (score 0):

Something like this..?

```sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @sql = N' '+ String_agg(Concat(N'
UPDATE ', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), Quotename(col_table_name)), N'
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];'), N'' + CHAR(13) +  CHAR(13))  
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  [condition]

EXEC (@sql)
```

Once you get the query, you can check the query by using the `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT (@sql)
```

If the query is okay, then you can execute it.

```
EXEC (@sql)
```

Example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1011376/